# How to enable the communication templates for a particular user

Tags: email-template

How can I make the communication templates link available for user as he is unable to have the link and is unable to create HTML templates?

Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide **“Edit HTML Templates”** and **“Manage Public Templates”** permission to the profiles for the user to be able to create HTML communication templates.

Regards!

Ruchi